# All about SharePoint 2010 (Controls, WebParts, Themes, MasterPages)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've searched some FREE Controls, Templates, WebParts, Themes for SharePoint 2010, and its really hard to find good and free examples. Turned back into StackOverFlow and there is no Community Wiki for it. I want to open a Community Wiki about All Free SharePoint 2010 Controls, Templates, Themes, WebParts, etc... to collect them all in one topic.
For example, there is a site about MOSS 2010 Free Controls in [here](http://www.fileguru.com/apps/sharepoint_control_templates). This site containt most MOSS versions controls, web parts. I want SO Users to add most usefull web sites for SharePoint 2010 Developers such as Free controls, themes, tools, etc. I will be happy, If this question replaced with Community Wiki, for Beginners, Developers.. I want users to post helpful links. Eg, I was trying to make a new custom master page, and I found a web site or [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SHimUYnyuWM) about it. Please post it here

[SharePoint 2010 Master Page Tags.](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=386)

[Creating a Custom Master Page for SharePoint 2010](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/5224/)

Comment: this wiki could probably be added to the new sharepoint stack exchange 2.0 site

Comment: @Serkan: Not yet.. it is currently in the commitment phase but hopefully soon it will be apart of the StackExchange network.

Comment: @Kit Menke Understand. I hope it will be done. Because, SharePoint needs a platform like StackOverFlow

Comment: Damn right :) Help the proposal over on Area51 - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/sharepoint-overflow?referrer=dG23U6mCZgknXLaDPCj7kA2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not delete this question, but I gonna share this proposal link. So, if  someone goes to search SharePoint Community Wiki, can follow news on this link :)

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28921/sharepoint-overflow?referrer=dG23U6mCZgknXLaDPCj7kA2